# How to plot categorical vs numerical data with vioplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, categorical-data

I have a data set with a categorical column "colors", which has 4 colors. One of the other 2 columns is quantitative, and is called "pollen". I am trying to get vioplot to make 4 separate violin plots color vs pollen. Here is a data sample

[image]

The data is available at http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/beeflowers.txt

I made 4 subsets of the data with

```
blue <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="blue", select=c(pollen, colors))
green <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="green", select=c(pollen, colors))
purple <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="pruple", select=c(pollen, colors))
red <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="red", select=c(pollen, colors))
```

I then tried to plot a violin plot with

```
vioplot(blue, green, purple, red, names=c("blue", "green", "purple", "red"), col="yellow")
```

However I got this error

```
#Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
#  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Is there anyway for vioplot to plot pollen vs colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled "purple" when you subsetted. Also, in the vioplot function, your first four arguments need to be vectors, not data frames. This code should work.

```
blue <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="blue", select=c(pollen, colors))

green <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="green", select=c(pollen, colors))

purple <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="purple", select=c(pollen, colors))

red <- subset(beeflowers4, colors=="red", select=c(pollen, colors))

vioplot(blue$pollen, green$pollen, purple$pollen, red$pollen, names=c("blue", "green", "purple", "red"), col="yellow")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That piece of code leads to this error:Error in if (opt$nbins > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(data) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(data) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: I see that error message if I spelled "purple" as "pruple" or if I misspelled any of the other colors when subsetting. Can't think of another reason for why you're seeing that message.

Comment: You were right. I was looking for the spelling error elsewhere. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that is much less repetitive. When you find yourself typing the same thing over and over, like those four lines of subsets, it's a sign that there's a more efficient way.

In this case, `ggplot` takes data in the long form that you already have, so there's no need for any sub-setting or reshaping.

```
# import data
x <- read.table("http://www.uwyo.edu/crawford/datasets/beeflowers.txt", 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                header = TRUE)

# inspect
str(x); View(x)

# get rid of that 999, presumably missing data
x <- x[x$pollen != 999, ]

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(colors, pollen)) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image]

Comment: Similarly with lattice: `bwplot(pollen~colors, x, panel=panel.violin)`.

Comment: That is incredibly helpful! I appreciate it.